# Getting unknown API version when starting kind cluster

Tags: macos, kubernetes, kind

Trying to get kind running on Intel OSX 13.3.1 just to learn more about kubernetes.
Installed kubectl and kind using homebrew.

```
kubectl version 1.25.4
kind version 0.18.0
Docker Desktop 4.18.0
```

I can stand up the default cluster with kind create cluster

I looked in the ~/.kube/config file and it has apiVersion: v1

I deleted this cluster

Tried to follow an example to start up a multi-node cluster with this file. The file passed yamllint.

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

and this command

```
kind create cluster --config ~/.kube/kind_cluster.yml
```

And got this error

```
ERROR: failed to create cluster: unknown apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1
```

Any idea what may be wrong?

Note that I have tried numerous apiVersion values based on various other “hellowworld” examples and goggle-fu output with no luck.

Comment: You could start with [the documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/) which says you should be using `apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4`.

Comment: Tried that along with many other variations of apiVersion.

Comment: Sounds like that was, in fact, the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your APIVersion should be kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4 as per the docs here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/329a451909597f481bd3d313d054e9852537e2b9/site/content/docs/user/configuration.md?plain=1#L19-L24

I'll copy paste to avoid link rot though

A minimal valid config is:

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
```

Comment: OK that time it worked. I could have sworn I tried that before.

Comment: Maybe because I restarted Docker Desktop? No clue.

Comment: Maybe had contamination in docker from earlier experiments? Anything listed with kube or kind got nuked and docker restarted.


milliron@iMac:~/.kube/>kubectl get nodes
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
rays-cluster-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   55s   v1.26.3
rays-cluster-worker          Ready    <none>          23s   v1.26.3
rays-cluster-worker2         Ready    <none>          23s   v1.26.3
rays-cluster-worker3         Ready    <none>          35s   v1.26.3